# my windows form is hanging while retrieving data from database in c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating simple time table generator for clg project and for it I'm fetching 
name of teachers and their subjects from database and assigning them to labels on my windows form and for fetching the data I'm using sql data reader but what is happening is after clicking on generate time table button my windows form is getting hanged is there any solution?

I have tried using backgroundworker but it isn't working? I think its happening 
because my code is going in infinite loop condition or it may be because of sql exception...

```
public void Filler()
{
    constring = "Data Source=PRATIK-PC\\STORM;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    con.Open();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    int pika1 = 0, pika2 = 0, pika3 = 0, pika4 = 0, pika5 = 0, pika6 = 0, pika7 = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        month = rnd.Next(1, 8);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select subject,teacher from sybca where id='" + month + "'", con);
        if (i > 1)
            con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                idd2 = reader[1].ToString();
                idd = reader[0].ToString() + " - " + reader[1].ToString();

                if (i == 1)
                {
                    lb1.Text = idd;
                    count_1 = month;
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    if (month != count_1)
                    {
                        if (month == 1 && bool1 == true)
                        {
                            lb2.Text = idd;
                            count_2 = month;
                            pika1++;
                            if (pika1 >= 4)
                                bool1 = false;

                        }
                        else if (month == 2 && bool2 == true)
                        {
                            lb2.Text = idd;
                            count_2 = month;
                            pika2++;
                            if (pika2 >= 4)
                                bool2 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 3 && bool3 == true)
                        {
                            lb2.Text = idd;
                            count_2 = month;
                            pika3++;
                            if (pika3 >= 4)
                                bool3 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 4 && bool4 == true)
                        {
                            lb2.Text = idd;
                            count_2 = month;
                            pika4++;
                            if (pika4 >= 4)
                                bool4 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 5 && bool5 == true)
                        {
                            lb2.Text = idd;
                            count_2 = month;
                            pika5++;
                            if (pika5 >= 4)
                                bool5 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 6 && bool6 == true)
                        {
                            lb2.Text = idd;
                            count_2 = month;
                            pika6++;
                            if (pika6 >= 4)
                                bool6 = false;

                        }
                        else if (month == 7 && bool7 == true)
                        {
                            lb2.Text = idd;
                            count_2 = month;
                            pika7++;
                            if (pika7 >= 4)
                                bool7 = false;
                        }
                        else
                            i--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    if (month != count_1 && month != count_2)
                    {
                        if (month == 1 && bool1 == true)
                        {
                            lb3.Text = idd;
                            count_3 = month;
                            pika1++;
                            if (pika1 >= 4)
                                bool1 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 2 && bool2 == true)
                        {
                            lb3.Text = idd;
                            count_3 = month;
                            pika2++;
                            if (pika2 >= 4)
                                bool2 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 3 && bool3 == true)
                        {
                            lb3.Text = idd;
                            count_3 = month;
                            pika3++;
                            if (pika3 >= 4)
                                bool3 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 4 && bool4 == true)
                        {
                            lb3.Text = idd;
                            count_3 = month;
                            pika4++;
                            if (pika4 >= 4)
                                bool4 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 5 && bool5 == true)
                        {
                            lb3.Text = idd;
                            count_3 = month;
                            pika5++;
                            if (pika5 >= 4)
                                bool5 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 6 && bool6 == true)
                        {
                            lb3.Text = idd;
                            count_3 = month;
                            pika6++;
                            if (pika6 >= 4)
                                bool6 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 7 && bool7 == true)
                        {
                            lb3.Text = idd;
                            count_3 = month;
                            pika7++;
                            if (pika7 >= 4)
                                bool7 = false;
                        }
                        else
                            i--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i--;
                    }
                }

                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    if (month != count_1 && month != count_2 && month != count_3)
                    {
                        if (month == 1 && bool1 == true)
                        {
                            lb4.Text = idd;
                            count_4 = month;
                            pika1++;
                            if (pika1 >= 4)
                                bool1 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 2 && bool2 == true)
                        {
                            lb4.Text = idd;
                            count_4 = month;
                            pika2++;
                            if (pika2 >= 4)
                                bool2 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 3 && bool3 == true)
                        {
                            lb4.Text = idd;
                            count_4 = month;
                            pika3++;
                            if (pika3 >= 4)
                                bool3 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 4 && bool4 == true)
                        {
                            lb4.Text = idd;
                            count_4 = month;
                            pika4++;
                            if (pika4 >= 4)
                                bool4 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 5 && bool5 == true)
                        {
                            lb4.Text = idd;
                            count_4 = month;
                            pika5++;
                            if (pika5 >= 4)
                                bool5 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 6 && bool6 == true)
                        {
                            lb4.Text = idd;
                            count_4 = month;
                            pika6++;
                            if (pika6 >= 4)
                                bool6 = false;
                        }
                        else if (month == 7 && bool7 == true)
                        {
                            lb4.Text = idd;
                            count_4 = month;
                            pika7++;
                            if (pika7 >= 4)
                                bool7 = false;
                        }
                        else
                            i--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 5)
                {
                    if (month == 1 && bool1 == true)
                    {
                        lb5.Text = idd;
                        count_5 = month;
                        pika1++;
                        if (pika1 >= 4)
                            bool1 = false;
                    }
                    else if (month == 2 && bool2 == true)
                    {
                        lb5.Text = idd;
                        count_5 = month;
                        pika2++;
                        if (pika2 >= 4)
                            bool2 = false;
                    }
                    else if (month == 3 && bool3 == true)
                    {
                        lb5.Text = idd;
                        count_5 = month;
                        pika3++;
                        if (pika3 >= 4)
                            bool3 = false;
                    }
                    else if (month == 4 && bool4 == true)
                    {
                        lb5.Text = idd;
                        count_5 = month;
                        pika4++;
                        if (pika4 >= 4)
                            bool4 = false;
                    }
                    else if (month == 5 && bool5 == true)
                    {
                        lb5.Text = idd;
                        count_5 = month;
                        pika5++;
                        if (pika5 >= 4)
                            bool5 = false;
                    }
                    else if (month == 6 && bool6 == true)
                    {
                        lb5.Text = idd;
                        count_5 = month;
                        pika6++;
                        if (pika6 >= 4)
                            bool6 = false;
                    }
                    else if (month == 7 && bool7 == true)
                    {
                        lb5.Text = idd;
                        count_5 = month;
                        pika7++;
                        if (pika7 >= 4)
                            bool7 = false;
                    }
                    else
                        i--;
                }

                con.close();
            }
```

Comment: There is way too much code, here, consider wrapping some of this stuff in methods

Comment: Why are you closing and reopening the connection each time i increases?

Comment: In each record of the query you do a different thing, so far so good... But if you dont `order by column_name` your query, how do you guarantee your code will behave as you wish every time?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing I'd try is moving the con.Close() outside of the loop. It's not super easy to read what you posted here, but it looks like it's inside the for, just outside the using. Might not be the solution, as in my experience this should be throwing some kind of exception, but take a look at and see if it helps.

EDIT: Oh, and it probably runs forever because there's a bunch of cases where you decrement i within the loop. If the code ever enters any of those you find yourself in an infinite loop, unless the first iteration changes something that the next time around would put you in a different condition.

Comment: after moving it outside for loop it gives error connection still open when it itterated second time....

Comment: coz im using for loop when it iterates second time it needs open connection and vice versa with close

Comment: Yeah, you're right I didn't notice that you also open the connection inside the loop. I'd put that before the loop too. It probably won't help with the problem though. But just as a best practice try opening and closing connections as infrequently as the way you use the database allows. EDIT: I just noticed you also open it right after you declare the connection string. That Open should be enough.